# NLP Keras - Dimension of Embedding and Global Average Pooling Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, nlp

I am trying to trace the calculation of Tensorflow’s NLP neural network pipeline below.

```
embedding_dim=16

model = Sequential([
  vectorize_layer,
  Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, name="embedding"),
  GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  Dense(16, activation='relu'),
  Dense(1)
])
```

I am a little bit confused on the dimensions of the embedding and global average pooling layers.

For example, if I have a sample sentence vector `[‘I’, ‘like’, ‘Chinese’, ‘food’]`. The embedding layer will expand this vector from 4x1 dimensions to a matrix of 4x16 dimensions right? Then the global average pooling 1D will take an average of each **feature**, and return a vector of 16x1, where each value represents an average feature value of my sentence, am I correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) @tkhu
what you mentioned above is correct if something is wrong with the model it may be due to the vectorization part

Comment: Perfect! I was not sure because I’m new with the model, but thanks for confirmation!